# SQL query to find status of the last event of an order

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables (in a SQL Server database) as following:

> **TblOrders**
>   OrderID (PK)
>   (some more fields)
>
> **TblEvents**
>   EventID (PK)
>   OrderID (FK) (linked to OrderID of TblOrders)
>   EventDate
>   Status

Each event in TblEvents belongs to an order in TblOrders, and each event has a date and a 'status' (a numeric code). An order may have several events (at least one).

I need a SQL query that finds for each OrderID in TblOrders the status of the *latest* event among all its events. For Example:

Input tables:

```
TblOrders  
=========
 OrderID
       1
       2
       3

TblEvents  
=========
 EventID OrderID EventDate  Status  
       1       1 01/02/2011      4
       2       1 02/02/2011      2
       3       2 03/02/2011      2
       4       3 03/02/2011      3
       5       2 01/02/2011      1
```

Result of the query:

```
OrderID Status
      1      2
      2      2
      3      3
```

(OrderID 2 has Status 2 because it has two events, 3 and 5, and the latest of them is Event 3 which has Status 2.)

I hope I've explained myself clearly. I've tried to write the query for long time, but couldn't find the solution, so any help or hint will be welcomed.

Comment: Is it possible to have a case where there are multiple event_ids for an order_id on the same event_date with different statuses? If so, what is the selection hierarchy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select a.OrderID, e.Status
from (
   select o.OrderID, max(e.EventDate) latestDate
   from TblOrders o
   inner join TblEvents e on o.OrderID = e.OrderID
   group by o.OrderID
   ) a
inner join TblEvents e on e.OrderID = a.OrderID
where e.EventDate = a.latestDate
```

Comment: what's the use of the JOIN in the subquery? you already have `OrderID` field in the `TblEvents`.. what am I missing ?

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim: It is not possible in Sql Server, or at least it was not ten years ago, to have the max date and the status in the same table expression grouped by the id, hence the subquery. But you are right in that the orders table is not necessary. I must have answered in a hurry.

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.OrderID, a.Status
from TblEvents a
where a.EventDate =
 (select max(b.EventDate)
  from TblEvents b
  where b.OrderId = a.OrderID)
```

Note this will return multiple rows if more than one record for an Order has the same lastest EventDate.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT q.OrderID, q.Status
    FROM (SELECT e.OrderID, e.Status, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.OrderID ORDER BY EventDate DESC) as RowNum)
              FROM tblEvents e) q
    WHERE q.RowNum = 1
```

The same query using a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

```
;WITH cteRowNum AS (
    SELECT e.OrderID, e.Status, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.OrderID ORDER BY EventDate DESC) as RowNum
        FROM tblEvents e
)
SELECT q.OrderID, q.Status
    FROM cteRowNum q
    WHERE q.RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT TblORDER.ORDERID, MAX(tblEvent.EventDate), tblEvent.Status FROM TblOrder INNER JOIN tblEvent ON tblEvent.OrderID = tbOrder.ORDERID GROUP BY TblORDER.ORDERID... something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
SELECT DISTINCT(OrderId) OrderId, Status 
FROM tblEvents   
ORDER BY EventDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from TblEvents Where EventID IN(
  Select MAX(EventID) from TblEvents Group by OrderID
)
```

- Now Join this with any table you want