# MySQL find latest status per person per area

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a similar question to: [SQL query to find status of the last event of an order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169766/sql-query-to-find-status-of-the-last-event-of-an-order)

I tried to play around with the best answer, but due to only having one table, I didn't get anywhere.

Essentially I am looking for three queries that can find the LATEST status for one Person in a single Area, all Persons in a single Area or one Person in all Areas.

So here is my table:

**TblStatus**

```
ID (PK)
AreaID
PersonID
Timestamp
Status
```

This is the input data:

```
 ID AreaID PersonID   Timestamp       Status  
 1    1       1 2014-07-08 20:41:00      1
 2    1       2 2014-07-08 20:42:00      1
 3    1       1 2014-07-08 20:43:00      2
 4    1       1 2014-07-08 20:44:00      3
 5    2       3 2014-07-08 20:45:00      1
 6    2       3 2014-07-08 20:46:00      2
 7    1       2 2014-07-08 20:47:00      2
 8    2       1 2014-07-08 20:48:00      1
```

I would like the result of the first query to be the below if AreaID = 1 and PersonID = 1

```
 AreaID PersonID   Timestamp       Status   
   1       1 2014-07-08 20:44:00      3
```

I would like the result of the second query to be the below if AreaID = 1

```
 AreaID PersonID   Timestamp       Status 
   1       1 2014-07-08 20:44:00      3
   1       2 2014-07-08 20:47:00      2
```

I would like the result of the third query to be the below if PersonID = 1

```
 AreaID PersonID   Timestamp       Status  
   1       1 2014-07-08 20:44:00      3
   2       1 2014-07-08 20:48:00      1
```

I'd appreciate any helpful assistance. Thanks.

Comment: Results of 2nd query don't make sense shouldn't it be ID 7 with time 20:47 for person 2?

Comment: I think Query 2 is correct as there are 2 people in Area 1?

Comment: I agree there are two people.  but shouldn't it be returning timestamp 20:47 for person 2 in area 1.  timestamp 20:46 is for personID 3 in area 2.  Put another way: What ID has these attributes from your input data: `1       2 2014-07-08 20:46:00      2`

Comment: Ah apologies, you're right. I have updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you control 'your where clauses'

```
Select S.AreaID, S.PersonID, S.TimeStamp, S.Status
from tblStatus S
where timestamp = (
  Select max(timestamp) 
  from TblStatus B 
  where S.PersonID = B.PersonID
  --you need to duplicate the 'your where clauses' here too...
  )
And 'your where clauses'
```

--Without knowing the key on the tables this is challenging however this method prevents where clause duplication

```
Select S.AreaID, S.PersonID, S.TimeStamp, S.Status
from tblStatus S
where timestamp = (
  Select max(timestamp) 
  from TblStatus B 
  where S.PersonID = B.PersonID
  and S.AreaID = B.AreaID
  )
And 'your where clauses'
```

Comment: Thanks xQbert, I will try this out now. So I need to duplicate my WHERE clauses in the brackets and outside the brackets?

Comment: It depends.  Definitely for areaId and personID.  The inner query returns the max timestamp for whatever filtering you've done.  If your where clause would effect the results of that max value then definitely.  If not then no.  I guess a way to avoid that would be to join on S.AreaID as well.

Answer (score 0):

## First Query

```
Select * from `TblStatus` where `AreaID` = 1 and `PersonID` = 1 order by `ID` DESC
```

## Second Query

```
Select * from `TblStatus` where `AreaID` = 1  order by `ID` DESC
```

## Third Query

```
Select * from `TblStatus` where `PersonID` = 1 order by `ID` DESC
```

Comment: That would bring every status. I assume that by "the latest", the OP means just one.